# Sub folder directory browsing in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, directory-browsing

I have created a bucket in amazon S3 named "RootBucket". Inside the bucket created two folder "folder1", and "folder2". Inside the folder1, i have created 5 folders like F1, F2, F3, F4, and F5. Then inside the each folders(F1 - F5), i have added some images and, zip file.

the folder structure is like,

RootBucket -> folder1 -> F1 -> img1, img2, zipfile1, zipfile2.

I want do the directory browsers for sub folders here, like if i give the below link in browser,

www.sample.com/RootBucket/folder1

This will list the all folders(F1- F5) inside the "folder1".

If we click on any folder in the that directory list,

www.sample.com/RootBucket/folder1/F1

This will list all the images and zip files that inside the F1 folders. if we click on any image or zip file here, then it should download.

How to do this process in Amazon S3?

I have searched more place about this, they told me to use list.html java script to do list all folders. But i don't want use the link structure like

www.sample.com/RootBucket/folder1/list.html, instead of this i just want to give www.sample.com/RootBucket/folder1 to list all folders.

Please give me a solution to do this.

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

http://shrub.appspot.com should do what you're looking for. You'll need to write your own webapp using a server-side language, or you can fork Shrub and modify it for your own needs.